# How to specify a random slope only in glmer

Tags: random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to build a glmer model and want a random effect of individual ID but only need the random slope. I've been searching the internet for awhile but I'm still not 100% sure how to specify the random effect for slope only in the glmer model. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
results_full<-glmer(R0A1~MP_Perc+MPHW_Perc
                   +HW_Perc+YP_Perc+AG_Perc+Shrub_Perc+
                   Dist_PrimaryRoads+Dist_SecondaryRoads+(1+ID),
              data=secondorder,family=binomial)
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have `Y` as the response variable, `X` as the explanatory variable, and `group` as the grouping variable.

```
results_full<-glmer(y~ 1 + (-1+x|group),data=dat,family=binomial)
```

For example, if you want a random slope for `MP_Perc` and `MPHW_Perc` but no random slope for `HW_Perc` and `YP_Perc` and no random intercept then you would do

`glmer(y~ 1 + HW_Perc +YP_Perc + (-1+MP_Perc + MPHW_Perc|group),data=dat,family=binomial)`

Comment: or equivalently `(0+x|group)`

Comment: In my code above, R0A1 is the response variable (0=random location and 1=used animal location) and the explanatory variables are: MP_Perc+MPHW_Perc+HW_Perc+YP_Perc+AG_Perc+Shrub_Perc+Dist_PrimaryRoads+Dist_SecondaryRoads. Therefore, I want to specify a random slope for ID. Would I need to add in each x explanatory variable for an individual slope (e.g., (0+MP_Perc|ID)?

Comment: @AndyLittle I edited my answer, hopefully it's clear.

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat thank you very much! That makes sense! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @TrynnaDoStat `glmer(y~1+(-1+x|group),data=dat,family=binomial)` how does this 1 after  `~` work ?